# Gradle build failed when trying to deploy app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have absolutely no idea what is going on. I have tried every single solution posted in SO but the problem persists.

When synching Gradle files, everything goes smooth:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGetkeepsafeRelinkerRelinker121Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJakewhartonButterknife840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoRealmRealmAndroidLibrary120Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.906 secs
```

Then problem is when I hit the "play" button to run the app, this annoying error is thrown:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Running `gradle build --stacktrace` in the console, I get this message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '.../project-name/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.14.1. Current version is 2.11. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/jozan/projects/krimturstudios/adventures/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

Funny thing, I have set gradle 2.11 nowhere.. It is always 2.14.1.

In my Android Studio settings I have checked the option "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)".

In my project settings I have Gradle version set to 2.14.1.

This is my **gradle-wrapper.properties** file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

This is my project **build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my app's **gradle.build** file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "android-apt"
apply plugin: "realm-android"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.2"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Local
    compile fileTree(include: ["*.jar"], dir: "libs")

    // Testing
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"

    // Android
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1"

    // Butterknife
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0"
    apt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0"
}
```

Please anybody, this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

In cmd type gradlew. It should download 2.14 version.

Comment: Type it inside project folder. There should be gradlew and gradlew.bat files

Comment: Sorry I did not write it correctly "./gradlew". Problem still persists :(

Comment: In main build file add

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.0' // 2.14.1
}

Currently I'm using gradle 3 and everything is working great! But you can replace it with 2.14.1 :) And after this again use gradlew

Comment: Sorry, It changed nothing at all :/

Answer (score 0):

After deleting and cloning my repo, and add every change step by step I finally solved the problem.

Neither Gradle nor Android Studio were causing this but **Realm**!.

I had this field declared in a model Class:

```
private RealmList<? extends Item> items;
```

that somehow is preventing gradle from being build correctly. Removing allows building and deploying.

The funny this is that Realm does not throw me any error or warning... Maybe a bug.